# Copy folder chosen in input tag in a specific folder using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have an html template in django in which I select a folder using:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" onchange="getfolder(event)" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple />
```

In the `getfolder(event)` the content of the directory is shown in an output `span`. What I want to do is to copy the user selected folder inside the static django folder.

I can't put this folder at the beginning inside the static django folder because the folder that the user can choose is a folder of a really big database.

How can I do that using javascript or jquery ?

Comment: `In the getfolder(event) the content of the directory is shown in an output span` Are you certain this is working as you expect? In most browsers the folder structure of the client is obfuscated, or in some cases, completely inaccessible for security reasons. It's also not clear what you mean by 'put the folder inside a Django folder'.

Comment: Yes, it works. I used this site [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) where there is the "Reading files" part. And I added the possibility to choose an entire directory as I wrote before. What I want to do is to copy the folder chosen from input in another folder (static, always the same).